# Eclipse RCP Dynamic help customization

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Implemented eclipse dynamic help with 3.x with static html files earlier(html files located in soruce folder)

- Now the href for each topic has to be replaced with dynamic url, url 
  changes every day.So cannot map the url in context.xml.
- How can we pass the dynamic URL for each topic on the fly.

earlier implementation is with below api :

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().displayDynamicHelp()
```

Comment: Instead changing the URL you might create dynamic help content via the `org.eclipse.help.contentProducer` extension point.

Comment: hi howlger thanks, the dynamic help is context sensitive and is it possible to achieve listener registration and  retrieving context , then fetch, bind urls according with org.eclipse.help.contentProducer? and help content for each context id is hml with http request not static html files

Comment: The help content provider mentioned just returns an InputStream so it can get contents from anywhere.

Comment: implemented org.eclipse.help.contentProducer  extension and, this provided,but this class getting called when context.xml has the context also and getInputStream is calling recursively once the dynamic help is called. is there any other extension, that has to be implemented.? even when allowed all iterations being called on "getInputStream " method, returned input stream not showing in help page(returned inputstream of static html string).

Comment: @user961524 Instead of saying _" returned input stream not showing in help page"_, show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). `org.eclipse.help.contentProducer` works for me.